# How to give margin to nested div tag related to parent div tag using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Code:

```css
#b {
  width: 700px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.block {
  width : 10%;
  height : 10%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  margin: inherit;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id = "b">
  <div class = "block">hello</div>
  <div class = "block">hello</div>
  <div class = "block">hello</div>
</div>
```

I used the above code to give margin to the inner div tag but it's not working properly . . .

Comment: Can you explain your question more. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: Its not clear what your intended ui is. However, if you are trying to set margin, you might want to rethink `display:inline`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699967/displayinline-with-margin-padding-width-height and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448633/inline-element-does-not-accept-margin-top

Comment: Because of `display: inline;`

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

The reason why `.block {margin: inherit;}` isn't working properly is `display: inline;`.
`margin`, `padding` etc on an inline element do not behave as expected.

Briefly, inline elements have no concept of **'shape'**. `margin`, `padding`, `border`, `transform`, `width`, `height` etc are about **shape**, which means they **don't work properly/at all** on inline elements.

Please use `inline-block` or `block` instead of `inline`.

### Solution

I'm not sure what you exactly expect, but if you want to line up three `.block`s in the center of `#b`, please consider using `display: flex;`.

```css
#b {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Center children horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* Center children vertically */
  
  width: 700px;
  height: 150px;
  
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center itself horizontally */
  /* margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 20%; */
  
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.block {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  
  margin: 2%;
  /* margin: inherit; */
  
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  /* display: inline; */
}
```

```html
<div id="b">
  <div class="block">hello1</div>
  <div class="block">hello2</div>
  <div class="block">hello3</div>
</div>
```